# Is it just me or are the browser companies changing their upgrade frequency to max?

Tags: browsers

This has been happening for a while now and in our office we believe the crazy browser updates are due to HTML5 becoming so hot these days but is there another reason the browser companies are pushing updates so frequently.

Other than security updates.

It's a welcome change, else IE9 would become the IE6 just flipped over for many years to come so I was just wondering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has always had rapid release schedules, that is just part of Google's ethos.
Firefox seems to be increasing to almost catch up with Chrome (just my opinion).
IE/Safari/Opera don't seem to have increased that much.

You can avoid worrying about things like this by testing for features not versions.  So it doesn't matter what versions of browsers do x, y and z, just if your user is capable of running x, y and z.

Comment: Thanks Toby. I thought it may be because of a massive push towards HTML5 or improved HTML 5 features.